# How to build a dynamic MySQL INSERT statement with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post, show, implode

**Hello**
This part of a form is showing columns names from mysql table (names of applications installed on a computer) and creating a form with YES/NO option or input type="text" box for additional privileges to a application.. 
How can I insert it back to a mysql table using POST and mysql_query INSERT INTO????? 
Quantity of columns is changing because there is another form for adding applications with/without privileges..

```
<tr bgcolor=#ddddff>';

//mysql_query for getting columns names
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM employees") or   die(mysql_error());   
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    //exclude these columns bcs these are in other part of form
    if($row[0] == 'id' || $row[0] == 'nameandsurname' || $row[0] == 'department' 
            || $row[0] == 'phone' || $row[0] == 'computer'  || $row[0] == 'data') 
        continue;
    echo '<td bgcolor=#ddddff>'.$row[0].'<br />';

    if (stripos($row[0], "privileges") !== false) {
        echo '<td bgcolor=#ddddff><p><a class=hint href=#>
            <input type="text" name="'.$row[0].'">
            <span>Privileges like "occupation" or "like  someone"</span></a></p></td></tr>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td bgcolor=#ddddff align=center><select name="'.$row[0].'">
            <option value = "No">No
            <option value = "Yes">Yes
            </td>
            </tr>';
    }
}

trim($_POST); // ????

$query = "INSERT INTO 'employees' VALUES (??)";  // ????
```

Comment: where are you using html form tag? without that submitting form post can't be created and if you want to use on click event then use AJAX

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're not inserting ALL columns, you need to dynamically build an insert statement that will specify the columns you're inserting into.

First, create an array of the columns you want to use.  Use this both to generate your form and to retrieve the values

```
$exclude = array("id", "nameandsurname", "departument", "phone", "computer", "date");
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM employees") or   die(mysql_error());
$columns = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    if (!in_array($row[0], $exclude) {
        $columns[] = $row[0];
    }
}
```

Render your form from the `$columns` array:

```
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    echo '<tr><td bgcolor="#ddddff">'.$column.'<br />';
    if (stripos($column, "privileges") !== false) {
        echo '<p><a class="hint" href="#">
                <input type="text" name="'.$column.'">
                <span>Privileges like "occupation" or "like  someone"</span></a>';
    } else {
        echo '<select name="'.$column.'">
                <option value = "No">No
                <option value = "Yes">Yes
              </select>';
    }
    echo '</td></tr>';
}
```

Then, dynamically build your INSERT string from the posted values for those columns.  Be sure to protect against SQL injection:

```
$keys = array();
$values = array();
foreach ($columns as $column) {
    $value = trim($_POST[$column]);
    $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    $keys[] = "`{$column}`";
    $values[] = "'{$value}'";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO 'employees' (" . implode(",", $keys) . ") 
          VALUES (" . implode(",", $values) . ");";
```

Note: this will work better if you select from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` so that you can know the type of column you're inserting into.  That way, you won't have to quote everything.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` exists too :)

Comment: @Jack - yes, but it requires a `mysql_connect`ion, and the `mysql` library is deprecated in later versions of PHP

Comment: The reason I showed the line commented out is because if he tries out my code without an active connection, that line would fail.

Comment: @Jack - Derp!  Nice catch. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="dynamicinsert.php" method="POST" >
user name:<br>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username">
<br><br>
first name:<br>
<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname">
<br><br>
password:<br>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="add" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "your_username";
$password = "your_password";
$dbname = "you_DB_name";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

function insertqueryfunction($dbfield,$table) {
   $count = 0;
   $fields = '';

   foreach($dbfield as $col => $val) {
      if ($count++ != 0) $fields .= ', ';
      $col = addslashes($col);
      $val = addslashes($val);
      $fields .= "`$col` = '$val'";
   }
   $query = "INSERT INTO $table SET $fields;";
   return $query;

} 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    // Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
     $username_form = $_POST['username'];
     $firstname_form = $_POST['firstname'];
     $password_form = $_POST['password'];
     $you_table_name = 'you_table_name';

     $dbfield = array("username"=>$username_form, "firstname"=>$firstname_form,"password"=>$password_form);

     $querytest =  insertqueryfunction($dbfield,'you_table_name');

     if ($conn->query($querytest) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();

}  
?>
```

Comment: Hi sam, welcome to SO and thank you for signing up to answer this question. To make your answer even better, it would be good to add some explanations as to _why_ your code solves the OP's problem.