# How to create dynamic insert query using php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

This is my php array

```
   $j_obj = Array
    (
        [Cluster] => 1
        [Cost] => 48
        [Conversions] => 20
        [MyColumn] => 45
    )
    Array
    (
        [Cluster] => 1
        [Cost] => 46
        [Conversions] => 20
        [MyColumn] => 37
    )
    Array
    (
        [Cluster] => 1
        [Cost] => 47
        [Conversions] => 19
        [MyColumn] => 40
    )
```

**The above json array is not static one,it comes dynamically.**

I need to insert the array values in mysql insert query.I try the following

```
foreach ($j_obj as $row) 
{
  print_r(implode(',', $row));
  //$sql = "insert into $tbl_name values(implode(',', $row))";
```

// I got this value from printing the $row

```
  //1,48,20,451,46,20,371,47,19,401,51,6
```

what my need is

```
  //$sql = "insert into $tbl_name values(1,48,20,451),(46,20,371,47),(19,401,51,6)";
}
```

The table and columns are also created dynamically from json value,

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968982/how-to-build-a-dynamic-mysql-insert-statement-with-php)

Comment: here your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10944989/dynamic-sql-insert-query

Comment: Tx pankaj,franyne I see the link ,what is my issue is,the json array doesn’t have static columns ,it differs according to user selection.